# Assuming there is no human trafficking or any form of coercion, is there a difference between the penalties on pimp/madam and prostitute in the U.S?

Tags: united-states, prostitution

I was reading https://prostitution.procon.org/us-federal-and-state-prostitution-laws-and-related-punishments/ and unfortunately it only shows the difference in prostitute vs. client/customer. For example in New York, customers will get higher penalty than the prostitutes.

But I wonder if in practice there is any *difference between penalties* on pimp/madam (people who organize and introduce prostitutes to customers and of course, collecting part of their earnings) and prostitute (who directly providing sex to customers), assuming there is no abuse or human trafficking or any form of coercion or child prostitution (all parties are adults with full consent)? I am talking about the case in U.S. where for most of the places prostitution is illegal.

I know in some countries, organizing prostitution is considered as a bigger crime/misendeavor than  prostitution, but I am not sure if this is the case in United States.